# How to read integers from file to list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
def make_number_list(a_file):

     number_list= []

     for line_str in a_file:
         line_list = line_str.split()
         for number in line_list:
             if number != " ":
                 number_list.append(number)
         return number_list

opened_file = open(input("Name of input file: "))
a_file_list = make_number_list(opened_file)

print(a_file_list)
print("Length: ", len(a_file_list))
```

I am trying to read (eventually) 1000 **integer** values from a file into a list.. then find their max, min and i th value. However, this is not working to read the list (I'm just using a test list which is a file in TextEdit and is a bunch of random numbers separated by a single white space). Any suggestions?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Your `return` is in the for loop. So your method will exit at the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

```
# assumes Python 3.x
def read_nums(fname):
    with open(fname) as inf:
        return [int(i) for i in inf.read().split()]

def main():
    fname = input("Name of input file: ")
    nums = read_nums(fname)
    print("Read {} numbers".format(len(nums)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the numbers are present in your input file. Nonetheless, there are a few changes you could do to your code:

- Move the `return` statement outside the loop.
- A better way of checking if `number` exists would be:

  ```
  if number.isdigit():
  ```

Which gives you:

```
def make_number_list(a_file):
    number_list= []
    for line_str in a_file:
        line_list = line_str.split()
        for number in line_list:
            if number.isdigit():
                number_list.append(number)
    return number_list
```